# Global variable in Matlab that retains an old value and won't change

Tags: matlab, function, variables, data-structures, global-variables

I have created a function in Matlab and use the following run.m file to run it.

```
global kanasta
EEG_multitaper_autocor_SO_maheen_final(ALLEEG_LANCE_POST,'All','Cz-CPz',3,1,1,1)
POST=kanasta;
```

where `kanasta` is a variable generated from the function `EEG_multitaper_autocor_SO_maheen_final` and `ALLEEG_LANCE_POST` is a data structure.

From whatever `kanasta` (which is an array) I get from running this, I store it in `POST` as shown.

Then I change the code so that I run the following:

```
global kanasta
EEG_multitaper_autocor_SO_maheen_final(ALLEEG_LANCE_PRE,'All','Cz-CPz',3,1,1,1)
PRE=kanasta;
```

where I am using `ALLEEG_LANCE_PRE` is also a data structure with the same structure but just different data, everything else is exactly the same as `ALLEEG_LANCE_POST`.

I find that when I do this, there is some pre-stored version of `kanasta` that is incorrect and both `PRE` and `POST` turn out to be exactly the same thing. I am guessing its some sort of problem with the `global kanasta` which is declared global in my run.m file as well as the function as well. I am not sure why this is happening (it was fine before... my Matlab crashed last night and after that this has happened). And its messing up any further analysis I need to do on `PRE` and `POST`. I have also tried to save `PRE` to another variable and then running the code for `POST` and saving that, but it doesn't seem to work. I have cleared the workspace multiple times and cleared all variables and command history and restarted, but nothing works.

Does anybody have any advice on "resetting" perhaps? Or about global variables or why this might be happening?

Comment: Do you mean that you have restarted matlab? In that cas my answer will not work. If you have restarted Matlab and all resources are not cleared, the we are talking about a bug.

Comment: Nope I didn't restart Matlab..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Matlab global variables really are global, not just global in one script or program. They are not exactly global for matlab, but unless cleared they will keep their value until the Matlab session ends. The solution is to write:

```
clear global;
```

when you want to clear the global variables. However, in older versions of matlab the variables will keep exist as local variables. Which are cleared in the same way as usual.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... I did this but now that I am running run.m again the variable now comes up as empty... I am trying to declare some new variables as well but they are all coming up empty ... no idea whats going on

Comment: Ok so after everything was becoming stupidly messed up and unreliable I quit matlab and restarted it, its fine now, back to normal.

Comment: What is the problem with variables are coming up empty? To me it makes sense. In c++ global variables have file scope. This means that they are initiated before the program starts (before `int main()`) and destroyed when the program ends. Further, unless the variables are given a value (or `null`) they are then initiated as `0` or can be initiated later if there is not a basic type such as `int, double, ...`. I would say that initialize as empty in Matlab is an adaption to this.

Comment: @MaheenSiddiqui To avoid the problem to arise again I stongly recommend to have a `clear global` at the end. Further, to avoid the variable to be initiated as empty try to set a default value. Further, are you sure you really need globals here? The problems you experience is the main reason why you normally want to avoid globals. If you do not need to define them in the beginning they does not really seem to be global...

Comment: Actually I am making it global because otherwise I can't access it outside the function... unless there is some other way to generate a variable to the workspace without declaring it global... I actually cannot set a default value since it is a 1x44100 array and it changes with different data sets I use....

Comment: @MaheenSiddiqui there are many ways to return variables to a workspace. One [declare output variables](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html) for your functions. You can also save data to an external [`*.mat` file](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html), a [delimited file](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html), or [some generic format](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html). [`assignin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html) is also an option. Hard to recommend an option without knowing what you're trying to do.

Comment: @excaza thanks for your comment. I said above I need to use the variable generated in the function for some other analysis. I can't say much more than that because I would have to recommend a 40 page mathematical paper to you or my 50 page dissertation that will explain it all :}

Comment: @MaheenSiddiqui you shouldn't need that much room to explain how a program flows. From the OP I don't see why you couldn't declare `kanasta` as an output of `EEG_multitaper_autocor_SO_maheen_final()` and eliminate globals entirely.

Comment: @excaza Ah yes you are right. I can most definitely do that, I probably didn't because at the time this global variable thing was the only thing I could think of... (I don't have extensive experience in matlab). Thanks